# Creating and displaying a bitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap

What would be the easiest, most **cross-platform** way to create a bitmap (2D array of integers, or a quad-tree) and display it on the screen? I would also like to be able to save it as a file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be said -- the *easiest* and *most cross platform* approach is probably to use printf, with something like:

```
// y and x loops would surround this...
unsigned char grayscaleValue = /* something */;
printf("%c",grayscaleValue < 128 ? " " : "X");
```

You could use more than two brightness values.

I also like both Qt and Juce; they're both relatively straightforward cross platform GUI toolkits. They can both be got up and running in an evening or two... the ascii printout (and its variations) can be done in an hour.